# Cleaning up a nested JSON column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I need help cleaning up a JSON column this is the query I have

```
select json_extract_path_text(response_text,'rule') from live.qamatha_responses limit 20
```

this is the column I am trying to clean:

```
[{"ruleSet":"ccc","rule":"ERROR MESSAGE -- 3.2.1","business-identity-match-failed":"Businessname","approved":true,"requirements":[{"key":"business-match-failed","value":"Businessname okay","type":"text"}]}]
```

Comment: How do you imagine your cleaned up data to look like?

Comment: I want to extract the value of rule from the column response_text @botchniaque

Comment: And what is your actual problem? is it the fact the the response_text is a JSON array? Which means there may be multiple rules for each response. Do I get your problem correctly?

Comment: Sounds right @botchniaque

Comment: was the answer helpful? @Emm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difficulty you're facing is the fact that you need to *expload* the input json array into separate rows. Redshift does not have built in support for that, so you have to resort to a less obvious solutions.

`input` is a table that contains the json array column you want to clean up. I duplicated the input array to contain 2 json objects (in your example, the array had only one object).

`seq` is a helper table we'll use to cross join with the `input`. It should contain at least as many rows as is your json array length.

`exploaded_input` is a table that contains one json object from the array in one row.

I hope it's all clear now.

```
with input as (
    select '[{"ruleSet":"ccc","rule":"ERROR MESSAGE -- 3.2.1","business-identity-match-failed":"Businessname","approved":true,"requirements":[{"key":"business-match-failed","value":"Businessname okay","type":"text"}]}, {"ruleSet":"ccc","rule":"ERROR MESSAGE -- 3.2.1","business-identity-match-failed":"Businessname","approved":true,"requirements":[{"key":"business-match-failed","value":"Businessname okay","type":"text"}]}]'::text as response_text
), seq as (
    select row_number() over ()::int - 1 as i
    from (
             select 1 union all
             select 1 union all
             select 1 union all
             select 1 union all
             select 1
         ) as s
),
 exploaded_input as (
     select json_extract_array_element_text(response_text, seq.i) as response_text
     from input cross join seq
     where json_array_length(response_text) > seq.i
 )

select json_extract_path_text(response_text,'rule') as rule from exploaded_input
```

returns:

```
rule
ERROR MESSAGE -- 3.2.1
ERROR MESSAGE -- 3.2.1
```